# I want to Rotate my Sprite Kit Scene and have a SKShader applied to the scene at the same time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm using an SKAction to rotate an SKCamera right now, which intern rotates the scene. This works really great as gravity and all nodes (except the cameras children) are rotated as well. Now I have a chromatic aberration shader applied to the scene and every time I rotate the scene the background color of the scene immediately covers the entire screen. This happens regardless of shader used. I even made a shader that just gives back the exact texture and it still happens. Also just setting the cameras zRotation does not fix this problem, so it's not the SKAction causing this. This is the shader:

```
 void main( void )
{
    float divider = 200;
    float deltaX = sin(v_tex_coord.y * 3.14 * 10 + u_time * 4) * 0.01;

    vec2 rCoord = v_tex_coord;
    rCoord.x = rCoord.x - sin(u_time * 10) / divider + deltaX;
    rCoord.y = rCoord.y - sin(u_time * 10) / divider;

    vec2 gCoord = v_tex_coord;
    gCoord.x = gCoord.x + sin(u_time * 10) / divider + deltaX;
    gCoord.y = gCoord.y + sin(u_time * 10) / divider;

    vec2 bCoord = v_tex_coord;
    bCoord.x = bCoord.x + deltaX;

    vec4 rChannel = texture2D(u_texture, rCoord);
    vec4 gChannel = texture2D(u_texture, gCoord);
    vec4 bChannel = texture2D(u_texture, bCoord);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(rChannel.r, gChannel.g, bChannel.b, 1.0);;
}
```

Also this is the code to initialize the shader:

```
let shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "ChromaShader.fsh")
self.shader = shader
shouldEnableEffects = true
```

Thanks in advance!